# Ruby on Rails associating a User to another models text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

hello I have 2 models User.rb and Guest.rb.

in my app the user is responsible for entering the Guest information. I have a table in my views that will show all guests. I would like each guest row to display the user who has entered their information. Iam having some trouble properly setting up the current_user method in my controller methods. Currently iam grabbing the current_usera nd entering it next to every guest. Thank you so much in advance.

Controller:

```
  def new
      @guest = Guest.new
  end
   
   def create
   @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
   
     if @guest.save
         redirect_to  guests_path
     else
        render 'new'
   end
end
   
   def index
       @guests = Guest.all
      @user = current_user
   end
   
 
 def show
   @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
   @user  = current_user
end
 
 def edit
     @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
 end
 
 def update
     @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
     if @guest.update(guest_params)
       flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
       redirect_to @guest
     else
       render 'edit'
     end
   end
 
 
 def destroy
   Guest.find(params[:id]).destroy
   flash[:success] = "User deleted"
   redirect_to guests_url
 end

  
  def guest_params
      params.require(:guest).permit(:experience,:interaction,:mood,:guest_name,:room_num,:arrival_date,:departure_date,:opportunity_string,:employee,:notes,:opportunity)
 end
end
```

Models:

```
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    
end
```

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
        
        has_and_belongs_to_many :guests
end
```

Views:

```
body{background-color:white;}



</style>

<h1 class="text-center mt-3">Guests</h1>

<div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-x: auto; mb-3">
  
<table class="table table-bordered  text-center ">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#CFD2CF;font-size:1.4vw">
      <th>GUEST</th>
      <th>EXPERIENCE</th>
      <th>ROOM</th>
       <th>ARRIVAL</th>
       <th>DEPARTURE</th>
       <th>OPPORTUNITY</th>
       <th>EMPLOYEE</th>
       <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @guests.each do |guest| %>
      <tr style="background-color:<%=guest.mood%>">
     
        <td> <%= link_to guest.guest_name,  "/guests/#{guest.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= guest.experience %></td>
        <td><%= guest.room_num %></td>
        <td><%= guest.arrival_date %></td>
        <td><%= guest.departure_date %></td>
        <td ><%= @user.current_user%></td>
        <td><%=  %></td>
        <td><%= guest.interaction %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "guests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "experience"
    t.string "interaction"
    t.string "mood"
    t.string "guest_name"
    t.string "room_num"
    t.string "arrival_date"
    t.string "departure_date"
    t.string "opportunity_string"
    t.string "employee"
    t.string "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_guests_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "superadmin_role", default: false
    t.boolean "supervisor_role", default: false
    t.boolean "user_role", default: true
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "guests", "users"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that will help:

### Devise and `current_user`:

[Devise takes care of `current_user` for you](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers), so you should just be able to call `current_user` in your controllers and views.

`@user.current_user` isn't a method unless you've created one in your `User` model, which I would not recommend doing.

### Don't mix `@user` with `current_user`

It's possible to set `@user = current_user`, but I think it's a bad practice as it will get confusing quickly

`@user` should be tied to the model `User` and represent the user that the `current_user` is interacting with.

For example, a URL like `/users/1/edit` should set `@user = User.find(1)`.

The `current_user` could be someone else who is editing the `@user` object.

### HABTM Associations

Given an assigned `@user`, you can call `@user.guests` to get all guests associated with that user.

E.g. for a route that creates the following URL: `/users/1/guests` then your controller can have something like this:

```
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController

...

  def guests
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @guests = @user.guests
  end

end
```

And the reverse is true as well. For a route like `guests/1/users` you can call `@guest.users`.

But...

### Do you really want a HABTM?

If a `User` can create many `Guests`, but a `Guest` is never associated with *many* `Users`, then this isn't really a "has and belongs to many" relationship. You probably just want a simple `has_many belongs_to`.

I revisit [this article](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) often as a refresher when I'm considering my relationships.

Your schema has a `user_id` on your `guest` model, which indicates to me that you want to be able to say: "A User has_many guests. A Guest belongs_to a user."

But you wouldn't really say "A Guest can belong_to many Users"

### Code fixes

> I have a table in my views that will show all guests.

For ALL guests, this would be the URL `/guests`, which should map to `GuestsController#index`:

```rb
# guests_controller.rb

class GuestsController < ApplicationController

...

  def index
   @guests = Guest.all # or some scope like Guest.active
  end
...
end
```

For guests related to a give user, this would be the URL `/users/:id/guests` which should map to `UsersController#guests`:

```rb
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[show edit update guests]
...
  def guests
   @user.guests
   ...
  end
...

  private

  # this method sets @user for all views defined in the `:only` hash of the `before_action` callback.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
  end
```

> I would like each guest row to display the user who has entered their information.

Since you have a `user_id` field on `Guest`, if you switch to a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship, then you can just call the user:

```
<tbody>
  <% @guests.each do |guest| %>
    <tr style="background-color:<%=guest.mood%>">
   
      <td> <%= link_to guest.guest_name,  "/guests/#{guest.id}" %></td>
      <td><%= guest.experience %></td>
      <td><%= guest.room_num %></td>
      <td><%= guest.arrival_date %></td>
      <td><%= guest.departure_date %></td>
      <td ><%= guest.user%></td> <!-- guest.user instead of @user.current_user -->
      <td></td>
      <td><%= guest.interaction %></td>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

### Extra credit: use Includes to pre-load associations

Also, as a pro tip, calling `guest.user` could get slow because each `guest` record needs to make a call to the `User` table.

Rails offers [eager loading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for just this situation.

Change `@guests = Guest.all` to `@guest = Guest.includes(:user).all` and Rails will handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It has really cleared many things up for me . I also very much enjoy the `before_action ` method  in my controller that is extremely useful . I will take a look at the documentation and together with your answer here I should have something working shortly. Thanks again!